# Как правильно получить значение вложенным циклом?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть объект, с которого нужно достать свойства `name.` И пробежаться по каждому.

Но что-то не хочет доставаться. Ругается на ошибку:

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '27'

Вот код :

```js
 var json_date = {
   "dills": {
     "1": {
       "name": "boock_1",
       "time": "15:00",
     },
     "2": {
       "name": "book_2",
       "time": "15:00",
     },
     "3": {
       "name": "book_3",
       "time": "09:00",

     },
     "4": {
       "name": "book_4",
       "time": "05:00",

     }
   }
 }

 $.each(json_date['dills'], function(key, val) {
       $.each(val['name'], function(i, a) {
         console.log(i);
         $('h1').text(i)
       });
```

Comment: А зачем, говорите, вам нужен внутренний `$.each`?

Comment: Зачем в метках значится AJAX?

Comment: @ Dmitriy Simushev, мне просто нужно пробежаться по всем свойствам, name . и записать их значения в теги . пример <h1>boock_1 </h1> <h1>boock_2 </h1>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По вашим условиям цикл должен быть только один

```
$.each(json_date['dills'], function(key, val) {       
    console.log(val.name);
    $('h1').text(val.name)
});
```

Если вы хотите все эти параметры поместить в индивидуальный тег `<h1>`, тогда [так (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/cg8yt2sg/):

```
$.each(json_date['dills'], function(key, val) {       
    console.log(val.name);
    $('<h1>').text(val.name).appendTo('.headers');
});
```

Запись найденных значений в существующие теги [(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/cg8yt2sg/1/):

```
var ix = 0;
$.each(json_date['dills'], function(key, val) {       
    console.log(val.name);
    $('h1').eq(ix).text(val.name);
});
```

Если тегов не хватит, записываться никуда не будет. Добиться соответствия количества, думаю, труда не составит. В крайнем случае удаляйте все теги перед использованием предыдущего варианта.

Comment: если записать так как вы говорить то тогда в каждый тег выводится ток последне значение "name" . А нужно чтоб выводилось , по одном значению в каждый тег.

Comment: @Dementiy1999 значит ошибка еще и во второй строке цикла. См. дополнение

Comment: спасибо так работает. Но как быть если уже есть созданная разметка ? то- есть теги h1 уже есть . и в них нужно также по вставлять значения ?

Comment: @Dementiy1999 Покажите fiddle хотя бы. Хотя...

Comment: @ tutankhamun, добавил на фидл какая разметка , есть сейчас и какой результат пытаюсь получить : https://jsfiddle.net/sxzk9ooa/5/

Answer (score 1):

Это, скорее всего, потому, что Ваш циклоп получает `val['name']` там, где логично было бы передать `val`:

```
$.each(val['name'], function(i, a) {
```

Правильно:

```
$.each(val, function(i, a) {
```

Comment: если я использую val как мне потом правильно обратится к name. так чтоб когда цыкл проходил по каждому name он записывал значение name в в тег h1? например <h1>boock1 </h1>  <h1> boock2</h1>

Comment: Выше уже @tutankhamun ответил исчерпывающе. Я же немного запутался в Вашем коде.